# Compund index which overwrites previous document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a model for MongoDb using mongoose where I want to ensure that only one document exists for a particular user and file.

```
var FileStatusSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    file: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    user: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    hasSeen: { type: Boolean, default: false }
})

FileStatusSchema.index = ({file: 1, user: 1}, {unique: true})
```

Now, if I try to save a document with a combination of file and user which already exists, it raises a duplicate key error.

Is there some way with which I can configure MongoDB to overwrite the document rather than raising an exception?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I use upsert, do I need to specify the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if document doesn't exists this command will create new one

```
 collection.update({file:2112,user:21421}, {hasSeen:true}, {upsert:true});
```

Comment: So do I need to specify the index while using this query?

Comment: yes you must specify unique index,because when multiple clients uses this update operation at the same time and they are inserting document with the same user and file field then each update operation may result in an insert and there will be same document more then one

see documentation:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update